# SQL Query to transpose start and finish times into correct days

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, transpose

I have a data source which has employee swipe in/out in the following format

```
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+-------+-----------+
| Forename | Surname | Clock_Num | Date       | Time  | Direction |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+-------+-----------+
| John     | Kerry   | 0111      | 2017-09-21 | 18:00 | IN        |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+-------+-----------+
| John     | Kerry   | 0111      | 2017-09-22 | 02:00 | OUT       |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+-------+-----------+
| Bill     | Long    | 0112      | 2017-09-21 | 10:00 | IN        |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+-------+-----------+
| Bill     | Long    | 0112      | 2017-09-21 | 18:00 | OUT       |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+-------+-----------+
| George   | Takai   | 0113      | 2017-09-22 | 11:00 | IN        |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+-------+-----------+
```

Now I want to see these almost transposed to a single record per employee based on the shift start time like so

```
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+------------------+------------------+
| Forename | Surname | Clock_Num | Shift Date | Time In          | Time Out         |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+------------------+------------------+
| John     | Kerry   | 0111      | 2017-09-21 | 2017-09-21 18:00 | 2017-09-22 02:00 |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+------------------+------------------+
| Bill     | Long    | 0112      | 2017-09-22 | 2017-09-22 10:00 | 2017-09-22 18:00 |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+------------------+------------------+
| George   | Takai   | 0113      | 2017-09-22 | 2017-09-22 11:00 | Null             |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+------------------+------------------+
```

The part that has me stumped is the logic of the query.

ie if there is no clock OUT time greater then the clock IN time on a single day then look ahead to the next OUT but as long as it is before the next IN (In case employee forgets to clock out) then display as Null

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction?

I accept there may not be a simple 2-3 line answer to this it just needs to be relatively efficient due to large volume of records

Comment: Bill Long has two INs...were you aware of this?

Comment: Also, you should show more data, e.g. what happens if a person has more than one IN/OUT event.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Corrected, Thank you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen For the purposes of this a max of one In and Out event will be present for each day but one or either could not be present ie day off, not finished yet or forgotten clock in/out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) along with the `lead()` window function to get the `Next_Time` and `cross apply()` to get the next `Time` 'out' that is after `Time` 'in' but before the `Next_Time` 'in':

```
;with cte as (
  select Forename, Surname, Clock_Num, Direction, Date
    , Time = convert(datetime,t.Date)+convert(datetime,t.Time)
    , Next_Time = lead(convert(datetime,t.Date)+convert(datetime,t.Time))
        over (partition by Forename, Surname, Clock_Num, Direction
              order by Date, Time)
  from t
)
select t.Forename, t.Surname, t.Clock_Num, t.Date
  , Time_In  = t.Time
  , Time_Out = x.Time
from cte as t
  outer apply (
    select top 1
        o.Time
    from cte as o
    where o.Forename = t.Forename
      and o.Surname = t.Surname
      and o.Clock_Num = t.Clock_Num
      and o.Direction = 'OUT'
      and o.Time > t.Time
      and (o.Time < t.Next_Time or t.Next_Time is null)
      order by o.Time
  ) as x
where t.Direction = 'IN'
order by clock_num
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/UIMJ36919

returns:

```
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Forename | Surname | Clock_Num |    Date    |       Time_In       |      Time_Out       |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| John     | Kerry   |       111 | 2017-09-21 | 2017-09-21 18:00:00 | 2017-09-22 02:00:00 |
| Bill     | Long    |       112 | 2017-09-21 | 2017-09-21 10:00:00 | 2017-09-21 18:00:00 |
| George   | Takai   |       113 | 2017-09-22 | 2017-09-22 11:00:00 | NULL                |
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

---

For 2008, you can use `outer apply()` to simulate `lead()` like so:

```
;with cte as (
  select Forename, Surname, Clock_Num, Direction, Date
    , Time = convert(datetime,t.Date)+convert(datetime,t.Time)
    , x.Next_Time 
  from t
    outer apply (
      select top 1 
        Next_Time = convert(datetime,o.Date)+convert(datetime,o.Time)
      from t as o
      where o.Forename = t.Forename
        and o.Surname = t.Surname
        and o.Clock_Num = t.Clock_Num
        and o.Direction = t.Direction
        and ((o.Date = t.Date and o.Time > t.Time)
          or o.Date > t.Date)
      order by o.Date, o.Time
  ) as x
)
select t.Forename, t.Surname, t.Clock_Num, t.Date
  , Time_In  = t.Time
  , Time_Out = x.Time
from cte as t
  outer apply (
    select top 1
        o.Time
    from cte as o
    where o.Forename = t.Forename
      and o.Surname = t.Surname
      and o.Clock_Num = t.Clock_Num
      and o.Direction = 'OUT'
      and o.Time > t.Time
      and (o.Time < t.Next_Time or t.Next_Time is null)
      order by o.Time
  ) as x
where t.Direction = 'IN'
order by clock_num
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/LEYS1651

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response, Ive used your answer but I receive a "The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled." Message and unfortunately not your example answer... I've not dealt with PDW before... is it something I can enable in SSMS2012 or a separate installation?

Comment: Ahh although the target Version is 2012 the dev server I have been allocated is 2008 so Lead doesn't work... I can request a different dev server but just a check is there another way of doing in 2008?

Comment: @LRiley Updated with 2008 version